# Notification about number of review tasks

Tags: bug, review, notifications

I am sure that this has been addressed somewhere, but in case not.

1. Right now I see two review tasks when I click review. But on the front page (of main) I don't have a notification about the existence of these two.
2. Also earlier today I had completed some review tasks because of the notification on the front page (of main). I had 12 review tasks. I completed some, but the front page still told me that there was 12 to review.

Is this a bug?

Comment: For 1: by "front page" do you mean the front page of meta, or the front page of Math.SE?  There are separate queues for Meta review tasks and Main review tasks.

Comment: @anorton: I meant the front page of main.

Comment: @user147263: arh, that explains it somewhat.